# trying to cache js and css file with nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to cache .css e .js files.

At the moment in this way is not working:

```
location /static {
     alias /var/www/ttch/assets/;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
   access_log off;
   expires max;
}
```

With only this config, nginx serve correctly static file without cache:

```
location /static {
     alias /var/www/ttch/assets/;
}
```

Any hints about how can I merge this two directives?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need regex in that case? expires header can be applied to /static location.

Comment: I don't want to apply expires max to all /static/ file, but also on js and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)** or **[root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)** directive helps you to identify location on the file system, but location is self-contained block you can extend easily, so this will work properly:

```
location /static {
   alias /var/www/ttch/assets/;
   access_log off;
   expires max;   
}
```

If you want to serve files with particular extensions, try this one:

```
location ~ ^/static/(.+\.(?:css|js))$ {
  alias /var/www/ttch/assets/;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```